# $(this).val() returning empty on WTF with .on('input')

Tags: jquery, flask, flask-wtforms

I have a WTForm text field in a flask application with the id `start_date`

```
<div class="col-2 col-2-xsmall" id="start_date">
    {{ form.start_date(placeholder="Start Date") }}
</div>
```

I also have subsequent jQuery that I'm trying to log into the console.

```
var $start_date = $('#start_date')
    $start_date.on('input', function(){
        console.log($(this).text());
        console.log("Hello")
```

The end goal is to update the DOM when a regular expression is matched in the field, but during development, when I log `$(this).val()`, I'm getting back an empty string in the console. The additional log is just to sanity check, which does show up in the console when I press any key in the field.

```
nilread.wkx http://localhost:5000/query.html?query_id=1
main.js:217 
main.js:218 Hello

main.js:217 
main.js:218 Hello

main.js:217 
main.js:218 Hello

main.js:217 
main.js:218 Hello
```

This is the console when I type the number 1991, where I would expect the output above each Hello to be the value that is in the field instead of the empty string I'm getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure to have well understood, but first, why are you using a `div` for an input of type date ?
Also, you have talked about getting value of the input, but you use text method : why ?

Instead of a div, you should use HTML `input` (add `type="date"` if you want only to have date type) tag like this :

```js
/*
var $start_date = $('#start_date');
$start_date.on('input', function(event) {
    console.log(event.val());
    console.log("Hello");
});
*/

var start_date = document.getElementById('start_date');
start_date.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    console.log("Hello");
});
```

```html
<input class="col-2 col-2-xsmall" id="start_date" value='{{ form.start_date(placeholder="Start Date") }}'>
```

Note : I have used Vanilla JS because JQuery is not recognized in the snippet, so that you can execute it and see if it is what you want. The commented JQuery code should work.

Comment: I'll start off by saying that your code does achieve what I'm trying to get, so thank you! I'll mark it as an accepted answer.

The div is just for formatting the CSS. I'll play around with changing the input to type date and see what happens. Also, for the text method, I must have left that in accidently when I was frustrated and trying just anything I could find online. I had been using $(this).val() as the method to get the content

Comment: Your welcome, I hope you've learnt something :)

Comment: For CSS formatting, you should use a class attribute on the input, and update your style selector, and this should work.
It's better to use classes to create custom CSS, instead of using HTML components that are not really made for it.